# Do you lose Piety when your leader dies?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

These are the ways I've found to gain and lose Piety in Europa Universalis 4 so far:

- Random events: +/- 10 or 25
- Declare war: +/- X depending on the target's religion

Twice now in my game as the Ottomans I've been cooking along at +100 Piety when a conversion succeeds. I open the Religion tab only to find I've dropped considerably with no explanation: to +45 one time and +15 the other.

The second time happened very quickly. Within the space of two months starting at 100 Piety my leader died *with* an heir, I received a -10 Piety random event which should have dropped me to 90, and I converted a province. But the Religion tab showed me at +15 so *something* must have dropped me to +25.

Do you lose Piety when a leader dies, or does each leader come in with a random Piety?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Paradox Wiki Muslim Religion](http://eu4wiki.com/Religion#Muslim) section, you lose 75% on death. That fits arithmetically.

> When a new ruler succeeds to the throne, the Piety score is reset and 3/4 of the piety score is lost, the new sultan is not assumed to be as impious or as pious as his predecessor.